# Pregmatch to get contents between square brackets php

Tags: php, regex

I thought I found a solution here on stack that would work, but I might be going about it wrong:

```
$subject = 'RE: Reply to me [Quote #341 | some-site]';

preg_match("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

what I am trying to do is create an array where it comes out as:

```
[
    "Quote ...",
    "some-site",
]
```

Now this regex is suppose to get me the contents, I think, from the square brackets but all I get is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "[Quote #341 | some-site]"
}
```

Which is wrong. I want the contents inside the square brackets, with out the `|`

**Thoughts?**

Comment: While you could get a simple, 2 capture group answer based on the | dividing character, what have you done to attempt that ? `(?<=\[)(.*?)\|(.*?)(?=\])`

Comment: [Capture and explode...](https://tio.run/##Ncy9CsIwFIbhPVdxiEITqZSikz84CY61axJLfw5WaUhoUlHw3mMQun3D8722tyEcTsWlIGTppuaJrYcjJOV5ByXa4QPegEYQ18l4hMVmm8MXnNG4dg@PKtkTYke8V7r2bc9oJgUTN6nUikuV0RTmaFx/go7Hy6seq27SluHbDqZDRmOVpjMRueKRhfAD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\[\s*([^][|]*?)\s*\|\s*([^][]*?)\s*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/onQ9IG/1/).

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^][|]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `|` (as few as possible)
- `\s*\|\s*` - a `|` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `([^][]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (as few as possible)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `]` - a `]` char

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/QTnGm):

```php
$re = '/\[\s*([^][|]*?)\s*\|\s*([^][]*?)\s*]/m';
$str = 'RE: Reply to me [Quote #341 | some-site]';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
    array_shift($match);
    print_r($match);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Quote #341
    [1] => some-site
)
```